# Why my Flutter app is not running in iOS while working in Android?

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter

I have created an app and this is working perfectly on Android devices. Now I setup everything for ios and while running the app on ios, I am getting my app crashed on App launch with error in xcode

**- [I-ACS036001] Analytics screen reporting is disabled. UIViewController transitions will not be logged.
flutter: The Dart VM service is listening on http://127.0.0.1:63292/m68C0e-fgfE=/
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GADInvalidInitializationException', reason: 'The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized without an application ID.
Google AdMob publishers, follow instructions at https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-ios-update-plist to set a valid application ID. Google Ad Manager publishers, follow instructions at https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-ios-update-plist.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011094928d __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e318894 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110948d8b -[NSException init] + 0
3   Runner                              0x0000000102ee5062 GADApplicationVerifyPublisherInitializedAnalyticsCorrectly + 380
4   Runner                              0x0000000102e92916 GADEnvironmentIsSupported + 775
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114435747 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001144369f7 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001144394eb _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 1487
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011444a7f1 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 369
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011444b3b5 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 277
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011478fc06 _pthread_wqthread + 262
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011478eb97 start_wqthread + 15
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 6**

Here is my info.plist file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>newzup</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>news_app</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>

    <!-- Firebase Settings -->
    <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>FirebaseMessagingAutoInitEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>FirebaseDeepLinkingAutoDetectEnabled</key>
    <true/>

    <!-- Interface Orientations -->
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        <true/>
        <key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
        <string>ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511</string>
        <true/>
    </array>

    <!-- Additional App Settings -->
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
    <key>FLTEnableImpeller</key>
    <false/>

    <key>FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED</key>
    <string>NO</string>
    <key>FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_DEACTIVATED</key>
    <string>YES</string>
    <key>FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled</key>
    <false/>


    <!-- Other Keys... -->

</dict>
</plist>
```

please take a look, I think problem is due to google_mobile_ads.

Comment: `<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
        <string>ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511</string>` Isn't this the default application ID?

Comment: Your info.plist file is incorrect. Your  `GADApplicationIdentifier` key is one of the values in the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad` values array. You need to move it out of that array